# remove preview image from div

Tags: javascript, image-uploading

I Made a Demo for preview image before uploading is as follow.

```js
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result).show();
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#uploadphoto").change(function () {
    readURL(this);
    $('#preview').show();
});

$('#preview').on("click", function () {
    $('#uploadphoto').replaceWith(selected_photo = $('#uploadphoto').clone(true));
    $('#preview').removeProp('src').hide();
    $('#uploadphoto').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="uploadphoto" />
<img id="preview" src="">
```

But Problem is this is work when i have `<img id="preview" src="">`
What if i wants preview image in div section.
and remove image from div like

```
<input type="file" id="uploadphoto" />
<!--PREVIEW IMAGE IN THIS DIV-->
<div id="preview">
```

and after preview delete image on click.
its easy to understand if your answer in fiddle.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet it helps, 
If i understands correctly you want to remove img tag and show image preview in div section.

```js
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo('#preview').width(100).height(100);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#uploadphoto").change(function () {
    readURL(this);
    $('#preview').show();
});

$('#preview').on("click", function () {
    $('#uploadphoto').replaceWith(selected_photo = $('#uploadphoto').clone(true));
    $('#preview').removeProp('src').hide();
    $('#uploadphoto').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="uploadphoto" />
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Comment: after select one image if you select second one so first image isn't removed.and when you again choose it will show all image

Comment: Yeah because its appending image to div every time it creates new image tag.

Answer (score 0):

try with `div background-image in jquery`

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      // $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result).show();
      $('#preview').css("height", "300px");
      $('#preview').css("width", "300px");
      $('#preview').css("background-image", "url(" + e.target.result + ")").show();
      $('#preview').css("background-size","cover"); 


    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#uploadphoto").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
  $('#preview').show();
});

$('#preview').on("click", function() {
  $('#uploadphoto').replaceWith(selected_photo = $('#uploadphoto').clone(true));
  $('#preview').removeProp('src').hide();
  $('#uploadphoto').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="uploadphoto" />
<!--<img id="preview" src="">-->
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function Preview_Image_Before_Upload(fileinput_id, preview_id) {
  var oFReader = new FileReader();
  var fileArray = [];
  fileArray.push(document.getElementById(fileinput_id).files[0])
  fileArray.forEach(function(entry) {

    oFReader.readAsDataURL(fileArray[0]);

  });

  //console.log(fileArray)

  // oFReader.readAsDataURL(fileArray[0]);
  oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
    if (window.FileReader && window.File && window.FileList && window.Blob) {

      var elem = document.getElementById("uploadPreview");
      elem.src = oFREvent.target.result;
     // document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild(elem);
      document.getElementById("uploadPreview").innerHTML=elem;
    }



  };
};


function removeFns(){
  
  //document.getElementById("uploadPreview").innerHTML=null;
document.getElementById('uploadImage').value = ""
  document.getElementById('uploadPreview').src = "#";
  
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="uploadImage" onchange="Preview_Image_Before_Upload('uploadImage', 'uploadPreview');" name="termek_file" class="file_input" />
<img id="uploadPreview" onclick="removeFns()" class="uploadPreview" width="100" />
<div id="placehere" class="uploadPreview" width="100">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can clear the image by using this code

```
$("preview").remove()
```